# Extending Singletons with private scope in Ext 4?

Tags: javascript, singleton, extjs4.1, private-members

In the course of an ExtJS 3 to 4 migration, I have run into a snag I'm wondering if anyone has tackled: namely, how can I extend a singleton with private scope?

In Ext3 I would do this using Extend:

```
Ext.namespace("My.New.Obj");

My.New.Obj = (function() {
    var privateVar = 3;
    function privateFunc() { alert(privateVar); }

    var extendedObj = Ext.extend(My.Other.Obj, {
        newFunc: function() { alert(this.publicVar+privateVar); },
        publicVar: 4
    });

    return new extendedObj();
})();
```

As best I understand, I would create a singleton pattern using Ext.define but I don't know how to extend the internal object.

```
Ext.define('My.New.Obj', function() {
  var privateVar = 3;
  function privateFunc() { alert(privateVar); }

  var extendedObj = Ext.create('My.Old.Obj',{
    newFunc: function() { alert(this.publicVar+privateVar); },
    publicVar: 4
  });

  return extendedObj;
});
```

The only trouble with the above example is that I believe the super methods that were preserved in Ext.extend get overridden.

How can I extend a singleton while keeping private scope?

Comment: Any thoughts on extending classes (non-singletons) in such a way that you can hold different state among different instances ?

Comment: Evan's answer provided below does just that.  In that example, an object or class B is defined.  A simple definition would involve `var b_object = new B();`.  You can keep state in that object by creating a state variable: `return { fooVar: 3, ... }`.

Comment: Somehow I can't figure it out.  Why is it that this example always alerts 'test 2' , if instance #1 and instance #2 are created with different values for `privateInstanceVar`? http://jsfiddle.net/brilong87/d4Ymk/31/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Ext.define('A', {
    someMethod: function(){
        return 'a';
    }
});

Ext.define('B', (function(){
    var fn = function(){
        return 'b';
    };

    return {
        extend: 'A',

        someMethod: function(){
            return this.callParent() + fn();
        }
    }
})());

console.log(new A().someMethod());
console.log(new B().someMethod());
```

Comment: Great, thank you!  I didn't realize that extjs4 recognizes and interprets the extend keyword inside object literals.

Comment: One thing to note.  The above example with return an object definition (i.e. `function()`) and not a singleton.  To create a singleton, you will want to include the `singleton: true` flag in the return statement.